# Can't require webpack on webpack.config

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to start a webapp with three.js, and i want to use webpack for bundling everything together, but i can't seem to figure out to require("webpack") on the webpak.config, i have to do this in order to use the webpack.providePlugin

Here is my webpack.config.js

```js
var path  = __dirname;
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

And here's the error that appears when i run webpack
[Error on webpack run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfF6q.png)

The error only appears when i try to require webpack

Comment: did you install webpack ?

Comment: you don't need to require webpack in the config file. you run webpack from the command line.

Comment: that error is about path not webpack.

Comment: Updated image,was using wrong screenshot, i did installed webpack, when i run it without the require gives an error of  "webpack is not defined" on the new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ line

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using, and what version of webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 99% sure the problem is that you're using an old version of Node.js.

Here's your error message:

```
/home/eloy/Sites/proyectomi/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:10
const {
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

If you're using Webpack 4.3 or 4.4 (the most current versions), then the line in question, [line 10 of `lib/Compiler.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.4.1/lib/Compiler.js#L10), is the first line of this destructuring assignment:

```
const {
    Tapable,
    SyncHook,
    SyncBailHook,
    AsyncParallelHook,
    AsyncSeriesHook
} = require("tapable");
```

A quick visit to [node.green](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations-with-objects) tells us that object destructuring wasn't supported in Node.js until version 6.4.0.

The [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/) recommend using the current LTS release of Node.js:

> ### Pre-requisites
>
> Before we begin, make sure you have a fresh version of Node.js installed. The current Long Term Support (LTS) release is
>   an ideal starting point. You may run into a variety of issues with the
>   older versions as they may be missing functionality webpack and/or its
>   related packages require.

As of today (2018-03-30), that's Node.js 8.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

1) var path  = __dirname;

This line needs to be removed.

2) npm install webpack --save-dev

This will add webpack to dev dependencies.

Comment: try adding comma after ending of module bracket and before plugins